# Simple node server throws `EBADF` regardless of port

Tags: node.js, networking

Given the deliberately simple server setup below:

```js
const http = require('http');

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
    res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' });
    res.end('Hello, World!\n');
});

const PORT = 3000;
server.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server running on http://localhost:${PORT}/`);
});
```

the process successfully binds to the port, but upon making the first request, it crashes with:

```
node:events:495
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: accept EBADF
    at TCP.onconnection (node:net:2050:24)
Emitted 'error' event on Server instance at:
    at TCP.onconnection (node:net:2050:10) {
  errno: -9,
  code: 'EBADF',
  syscall: 'accept'
}
```

Changing the port makes no difference. I observed this behavior on both node 16 and node 18 but not on node 20.

I'm running this on an Ubuntu 22 machine.

I'm completely stumped.

Comment: You have closed the listening socket.

Comment: it's not a node problem, but a system tuning issue. basically means you are calling an operation on a file descriptor that is no longer in the correct state to handle that operation (like reading a closed file, opening a file that has been deleted, etc).